# variable is not modified in if statement CSH

Tags: csh

I have the following very simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh

set status=0
if ( 0 == 0 ) then
    ls ./dummyDir
    set status=$?
    echo $status
endif
echo $status
```

And the problem is that the last echo of $status is 0 while the first one is set to exit code which is 2?
Why is this happening? Why status is not modified inside if statement. The same equivalent of this in bash is perfectly working.

Comment: Another reason not to spend time coding with `csh` /-; . That is a simple test, I don't see anyway of fixing your problem except saving a value to a file and then `source`(ing) `file`. I don't have a csh to experiment with, so I don't think I'll be able to offer additional ideas. Good luck!

Comment: If your job requires that you continue to program with csh, Then order the Anderson and Anderson "Guide to C Shell" (or similar title), it is very well written, but doesn't dwell on the problems of `csh`. OR show your boss  [csh-considered-harmful]().

Comment: arg. [csh considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: It's actually much simpler @shellter; `$status` is just an alias for `$?` (or vice versa), so it gets overwritten by `echo`. This one isn't really on csh's many problems :-)

Comment: Thank you to everyone .... I am just hooked to support someone else old stuff. Honestly, I prefer ksh or bash.

Comment: @MartinTournoij : Ah, right, it's a feature! (-; ! Had forgot about `status=$?`. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$status` is an alias for `$?`; so it gets overwritten by the `echo`. You'll need to use a different variable name:

```
set ls_status = 0
if ( 0 == 0 ) then
    ls ./dummyDir
    set ls_status = $?
    echo $ls_status
endif
echo $ls_status
```

Outputs:

```
ls: cannot access './dummyDir': No such file or directory
2
2
```